# NestJS / Prisma : Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CustomersWhereUniqueInput'

Tags: typescript, types, nestjs, prisma

Today I'm working on a new project with NestJS, I'm pretty new to NestJS and in particular to Prisma.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/blog/nestjs-prisma-rest-api-7D056s1BmOL0) on the prisma documentation and tried to adapt it to my project.

As the error says, the problem occured inside the findOne function.

I think it's my gestion of types.

I have read a lot of things but nothing seems to correspond to the error I'm getting.

Here is my schema.prisma :

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Customers {
  Id    Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  Firstname String  
  Lastname  String
  Username String @unique
  Password String
  accounts     Bank_account[] 
}

model Admin {
  Id    Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  Username    String
  Password    String
  accounts    Bank_account[]
}

model Bank_account {
  Id      Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  Balance     Int
  RIB     String?
  owner     Customers  @relation(fields: [owner_id], references: [Id])
  owner_id    Int
  admin   Admin     @relation(fields: [admin_id], references: [Id])
  admin_id    Int
  log_id    Int  
  
}

model Logs {
  Id    Int   @default(autoincrement()) @id
  Date   String?
  Type   String?
  State   Boolean?
  Bank_account    Int    
}
```

My customers.services.ts

```js
import { CreateCustomerDto } from './dto/create-customer.dto';
import { UpdateCustomerDto } from './dto/update-customer.dto';
import { Get, Injectable, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';
import { isNumberObject } from 'util/types';
import { Customer } from './entities/customer.entity.js';

@Injectable()export class CustomersService {  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  create(createCustomerDto: CreateCustomerDto) {
    return 'This action adds a new customer';
  }

  findAll() {        
    return this.prisma.customers.findMany();  
    }

  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {  
    return this.prisma.customers.findUnique({ where: { id }});
  }
```

Everything seems alright with my controllers and modules.

I already tried to re-generate prisma.schema, I tried to add some useless values to my database, nothing seems to change.

I tried to change the `ìd` for `Id` but nest said `Cannot find name 'Id'. Did you mean 'id'?`

Answer (score 1):

> Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CustomersWhereUniqueInput'

Look at your column type for `id`:

```
Id    Int
```

when the primary key is a `Int` type, Prisma expects numeric ids in your queries.

So convert that string to an integer before you pass it to Prisma.

```
  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {  
    return this.prisma.customers.findUnique({ where: { id: parseInt(id) }});
  }
```

Comment: I tried it, but I still have this error ```Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CustomersWhereUniqueInput'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'id' does not exist in type 'CustomersWhereUniqueInput'.```

Comment: I just deleted the types and keep this code: 
```findOne(@Param('id') id) { return this.prisma.customers.findUnique({ where: (id) }); }``` 
Now I have an other error, ```Got invalid value '1' on prisma.findUniqueCustomers. Provided String, expected CustomersWhereUniqueInput:
type CustomersWhereUniqueInput```, I can't convert my value to an Int, I'll continue to work on it!

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error recently, the problem was coming from the Controller function not named as the function in the service

so in your case

```js
 findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {  
    return this.prisma.customers.findUnique({ where: { id: parseInt(id) }});
  }
```

would be

```js
// replace findOne by findUnique
 findUnique(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.prisma.customers.findUnique({ where: { id: parseInt(id) }});
  }
```

I don't know if NestJs have preset named function or have a rule to look at the  prisma function but it could be good to give it a try

As I said it worked for me so if you try it I would like to ear your feedback

Comment: Also Decorator as **@Get(':id')** should be in the controller (if you have one), not the service !

Answer (score 0):

All @Params are STRING, you need to convert that id: string to number:

```
  // NestJS 10 - Prisma v5.10
  // customers.service.ts
  async findOne(id: number) {
    return this.databaseService.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id,
      }
    })
  }
  // customers.controller.ts
  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number) {
    return this.userService.findOne(id);
  }
```

'ParseIntPipe' converts you 'id: string' in to id: number.
Also - all your @Get request functions must be in 'customers.controller.ts' file and all 'business' logic should go to 'customers.service.ts' file.